# Remove substring from end of string Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to remove wwww.po.com from the end of my string.

string:
"https://www.po.com/dw/test1 https://www.po.com/dw/test2 https://www.po.com/dw/test3
https://www.po.com https://www.po.com"

So the output would be:
"https://www.po.com/dw/test1 https://www.po.com/dw/test2 https://www.po.com/dw/test3"

I've tried a couple of $split and aggregations but I either lose all www.po.com or am left with just https://www.po.com/dw/test1. The URLs and the amount of substrings is not consistent.

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If order is not important, you could use `$setUnion` with `$reduce`.  Assuming you want to update the existing collection:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
    [{$set:{
          string:{
              $reduce:{
                   input:{$split:["$string"," "]},
                   initialValue:[],
                   in:{$setUnion:["$$value",["$$this"]]}
              }
         }
    }}]
)
```